# Configuration problems with GeoServer 2.6 under Ubuntu

Tags: geoserver

I installed GeoServer on Ubuntu Linux 14.04 using the OS-independent binary that comes with Jetty. I am running it using the bin/startup.sh file. I am trying to create an ImageMosaic. When I try, I get this error message in the browser console:

```
ReferenceError: Wicket is not defined
```

I also get odd error messages in the console here and there, complaining about not finding JQuery - and yet, according to Firebug, the JQuery JS and CSS files get found and download OK.

Comment: Do you actually have 2.6.1? Are you using Firefox? Does it take a very long time to get the page to display?

Comment: I have 2.6.1 from the GeoServer website, I use Firefox and it doesn't take any time and all to get the page to display.

Comment: Can you try with 2.6.0? There was a compression related bug that was recently found and fixed, but its not in a released version yet.

Comment: I tried 2.6.0 and these problems mysteriously disappeared. Now there are others, of course, such as being incredibly slooooooooooow and unresponsive. Not sure what went wrong there.